# Multi-platform Unicode handling based on char* in C without using 3rd party libraries?

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, utf-8

The following are bare minimum examples (I know that e.g. UNICODE/_UNICODE should be defined) that I've found to work:

Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char* str = "Rölf";
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wchar_t* str = L"Rölf";
  wprintf(L"%s\n", str);
}
```

Now, I've read that [one way of going about it](http://utf8everywhere.org/#windows) is to basically "just use UTF-8/char everywhere and worry about platform-specific conversion when you do API calls".

And that would be great - have users provide char* as input for my library and "simply" convert that. So I've tried the following snippet based on [this example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) (I've also seen it in variations elsewhere). If this would actually work, it would be amazing. But it doesn't:

```
  char* str = u8"Rölf";
  int len = mbstowcs(NULL, str, 0) + 1;
  wchar_t wstr[len];
  mbstowcs(wstr, str, len);
  wprintf(L"%s\n", wstr);
```

I've also stumbled across discussions about console fonts and whatnot being the cause of faulty rendering, so to demonstrate that this is not a console issue - the following doesn't work either (well - the L"" literal does. The converted u8 literal doesn't):

```
  MessageBoxW(NULL, wstr, L"Rölf", MB_OK);
```

[image]

Am I misunderstanding the conversion process? Is there a way to make to this work? (Without using e.g. ICU)

Comment: Which system requires (or even just benefits from having) `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` defined?

Comment: Wide characters use 2 or 4 bytes per character; UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding.  If you have C11 support on all relevant platforms (as it appears you do) then [`u8`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5) etc may help.  There is some support in standard C11 in the header [§7.28 Unicode support `<uchar.h>`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.28), but not all implementations support that, even if they support other parts of C11 (witness: macOS 10.13.6 does not have it).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Windows will use the ANSI versions for API calls you make if you don't define UNICODE. (Unless I guess you call the "wide" version explicitly like I did with `MessageBoxW` above)
Also - as my question demonstrates, I'm not particularly familiar with Unicode. But there may be other reasons for why both MSDN and utf8everywhere recommend it.

Comment: Don't pay attention to "UTF8 everywhere" You can't use UTF8 with WinAPI functions.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Can you cite documentation that it doesn't work on Windows versions that allow UTF-8 as the "codepage" (April beta and later)? I can't see any reason why that should be. You can also use UTF-8 with the WinAPI functions if you're using [midipix](https://www.midipix.org), regardless of Windows version.

Comment: @R.. I can't find such documentation to confirm a negative. I don't think Microsoft can add UTF8 support without adding a separate set of APIs. Windows supports two sets of APIs for [UTF16 and ANSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings). You can change the system language, that changes the ANSI code page (requires logout/login if I am not mistaken). But UTF8 is not ANSI. If Windows ANSI functions were to interpret input as UTF8, it would become incompatible with old ANSI programs.

Comment: `_setmbcp(65001)` doesn't seem to do anything on my Win10 (build 17134), maybe I have an older Windows version, or maybe it expects ANSI code page. `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001); printf(u8"Greek Έλληνες\n");` handles UTF8 successfully on Windows 10. But that's for the console only (also add `SetConsoleCP(65001)` for console input). `MessageBoxA` still uses the ANSI code page for system language. The only time you can reliably substitute `65001` (or `CP_UTF8`) for ANSI code page, is in `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: As I said, it's new functionality in the April beta of Windows 10. Prior to that, UTF-8 was explicitly banned from being the "ANSI codepage" (a misnomer; it really means the multibyte encoding in the language of the C standard) for political reasons that they falsely claimed were technical, and that's finally become enough of a liability that they're backtracking and finding the technical issue was basically a non-issue.

Comment: @R.. Yes there is finally some UTF8 support for console programs. I meant Windows functions like `MessageBoxA` and `MessageBoxW`, as mentioned by OP. These core APIs just can't handle UTF8.

Comment: @R.. Huh, that midipix approach (adding multibyte APIs) seems intriguing! If I was more experienced with native coding, I might try to write something that does exactly that. (Since I find their docs to be very lacking, using midipix or at least looking at how they did it doesn't really seem like an option)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I don't see any reasons why the WinAPI functions like `MessageBoxA` wouldn't support UTF-8 if the "ANSI codepage" is set to UTF-8. If there is a good reason I'm not aware of please cite it or test rather than just repeatedly claiming that without evidence.

Comment: @R.. You are the one making a claim about some Windows 10 versions, you should show the documentation. I don't know. I don't even know how to change the systems wide ANSI code page without going through system's language settings, and UTF8 is not available as a language. I tried `_setmbcp(65001); MessageBoxA(0, u8"Greek Έλληνες", 0, 0);` it didn't work.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: It's in the Wikipedia link I posted in a comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows#UTF-8

Comment: @R.. Sorry, I missed that earlier. That's awesome. It really is UTF8 support for core APIs. It requires setting a specific option and restarting the system, it also runs in to problems with old ANSI programs. It's good for developers computers for now, hopefully it expands in future.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Yes, it'll be a while before anyone can rely on it, but it means things look good for the future where up-to-date Windows 10 is a baseline you can assume, especially if `_setmbcp` or similar works (so it's not dependent on the user setting a global option).

Comment: @R..: Using UTF-8 for the 'ANSI' versions of the Windows API still imposes some of the old restrictions. The native API uses UTF-16, so input has to be converted from UTF-8 to UTF-16 and vice versa for output. That means, you are still restricted to arbitrary conversion buffer size limits (see e.g. [CreateFileA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea)), and runtime overhead. The conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 being lossless does remove an error mode, but there is still merit in using UTF-16 in a Windows application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Barmak Shemirani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687784/multi-platform-unicode-handling-based-on-char-in-c-without-using-3rd-party-libr?noredirect=1#comment90340072_51688065) making me aware of `MultiByteToWideChar`, I've found a solution to this that is even C99 conform. (Which works on Windows 7 by the way)

Note that `setlocale()` is only necessary for console output to render correctly. I didn't use it to highlight that it doesn't seem to be needed for GUI-related API calls.

```
#define UNICODE
#define _UNICODE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
//#include <locale.h>

wchar_t* toWide(char* str) {
  int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, NULL, 0);

  wchar_t* wstr = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * wchars_num);
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, wstr, wchars_num);

  return wstr;
}

int main() {
  // For output in console to render correctly - as far as the font allows anyway...
  //setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  // PLATFORM-AGNOSTIC DATA STRUCTURE WITH UTF-8 TEXT
  // (Usually not directly next to the platform-specific API calls...)
  char* str = "Rölf";

  // PLATFORM-SPECIFIC TEXT HANDLING
  wchar_t* wstr = toWide(str);
  printf("%ls\n", wstr);

  MessageBox(NULL, wstr, L"Rölf", MB_OK);
  free(wstr);
}
```

The way I use it is that I declare a data structure to be filled by my users where all text is char* and assumed to be UTF-8. Then in my library, I use platform-specific UI APIs. And in the case of Windows, doing the above UTF-16 conversion is obviously necessary.

Comment: If you want to follow the idiotic recommendations from utf8everywhere then go ahead. Experienced Windows programmers use UTF16 only. There is legitimate usage for UTF8, for example saving files in UTF8 is easier and more compatible, web pages need UTF8 standard...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: There's nothing idiotic about utf8everywhere. If you want the core of your software to be clean and cross-platform, not full of Windows-specific madness, it's the right thing to do.

Comment: @R.. WinAPI is platform specific to begin with. Adding UTF8 compatibility to these incompatible WinAPI functions doesn't make any sense. You can advocate cross platform tools, or separate the UI from worker threads... Otherwise system APIs have to use native encoding.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It absolutely makes sense if you're writing a platform-agnostic UI library. Makes its use more convenient if users can supply the data in UTF-8 regardless of the platform (for both the user and me, since I don't have to have manage duplicate data structures). Why does the precise point in time at which the conversion to UTF-16 happens get you riled up so much anyway? You even argue to separate the UI yourself. That's exactly what this approach does?

Comment: @AndyO Sure, that's perfectly legitimate for cross platform code. Your aim wasn't clear to me.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Great! Thanks for the additional confirmation, I'll mark this answer as the solution then, since both R.. and you seem to find it acceptable. :) (I also edited it to try and make things clearer, like separation of data and UI handling and intended use case)

Comment: @AndyO Note that C++11 and later have [`std::wstring_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) to convert between UTFs. You are clearly using C++11 by virtue of using `u8""` for creating a UTF-8 string literal. `MultiByteToWideChar()` is specific to Windows only. `std::wstring_convert` is portable, and can be used in as little as 1 line of code. There are plenty of posts on StackOverflow showing the various ways to convert strings between UTFs. Look around.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I came across it but for one thing, I don't use C++ in this particular project and for another, the `u8""` was merely because I thought that maybe UTF-8 strings have to be created this way. I was obviously wrong about that. The code from my answer works with C99 and I think that's great and important because it's something I had not come across in many hours of research and many people still use C99 (like the author of the library that I'm basing mine on).

Comment: @AndyO "*I don't use C++ in this particular project*" - you're right, I didn't notice the `c` tag, just the `u8`, and forgot that C11 has `us`, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No worries, thanks for trying to let me know about a possibly more convenient workflow. :)

Comment: As an aside, simply reserving 3 u8 per u16 respectively 1 u16 per u8 depending on conversion-direction, while a bit wasteful, has the advantage of simplicity and speed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: `std::wstring_convert` is simple, convenient, portable. And deprecated in C++17. As far as I know, there is no replacement anywhere near standardization.

Answer (score 3):

The `mbstowcs` function converts from a string *encoded in the current locale's encoding* to `wchar_t[]`, not from UTF-8 (unless that encoding is UTF-8). On post-April-beta-2018 versions of Windows 10 or later, you actually *can* fix Windows to use UTF-8 as the encoding for plain `char[]` strings either as a global setting, or presumably by calling `_setmbcp(65001)`. Older versions of Windows explicitly forbid this however for dubious historical reasons.

Anyway, you second version of the code which you called "Windows" should work on arbitrary systems if not for a bug in MSVC's `wprintf` that you worked around: they have the meanings of `%ls` and `%s` backwards for the wide stdio functions. In standard C, you need `%ls` to format a `wchar_t[]` string. But there's actually no reason to use `wprintf` there at all, and in fact `wprintf` is highly problematic because you can't mix it with byte-oriented stdio (doing so invokes undefined behavior). So better would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  wchar_t* str = L"Rölf";
  printf("%ls\n", str);
}
```

and this version should work correctly on Windows and standards-conforming C implementations, since for the byte-oriented `printf` functions, MSVC doesn't have the meaning of `%s` and `%ls` reversed.

If you really want to, you can also use a variant of your third version of the code, but you can't use `mbstowcs` to convert from UTF-8 to `wchar_t`. Instead you need to either:

1. Assume `wchar_t` is Unicode-encoded, and convert from UTF-8 to Unicode codepoints with your own (or a third-party library's) UTF-8 decoder. But this is a bad assumption, because MSVC is also non-conforming in that it uses UTF-16 for `wchar_t` (C explicitly forbids "multi-`wchar_t`-characters because the mb/wc APIs are inherently incompatible with them), not Unicode codepoint values (equivalent to UTF-32).
2. Convert from UTF-8 to `uchar32_t` (UTF-32) with your own (or a third-party library's) UTF-8 decoder, then use `c32rtomb` to convert to `wchar_t[]`.
3. Use `iconv` (standard on POSIX systems; available as a third-party library on Windows) to convert directly from UTF-8 to `wchar_t`.

---

UTF8 option for Windows 10, version 1803+

[image]

Comment: Any reference for Windows 10 finally allowing and working properly with UTF-8 as codepage? Any linitations there?

Comment: So if I understand your explanation correctly: Either wchar_t would have to be my default type everywhere (and disregard utf8everywhere's suggestion "Do not use wchar_t or std::wstring in any place other than adjacent point to APIs accepting UTF-16."?) or I have to use a 3rd party UTF8-Decoder or write my own?

Comment: @AndyO: I would still strongly recommend using UTF-8 everywhere internally, and simply converting to `wchar_t[]` at the point of passing to/from Windows APIs. My answer is addressing the specific isolated code in your question, not an overall approach to use.

Comment: Hm... maybe I should have elaborated on what my code pieces are about. Because the whole point is that I was trying to figure out how to do that conversion. I was hoping that there would be a short way of doing it using standard functions like `mbstowcs` (hoping that I simply used it wrong). But apparently, I would have to start my research from the beginning and look for compact UTF-8 decoders (not big on adding lots of library overhead onto my 20 KB worth of code). Well - of course you already suggested e.g. iconv.

Comment: @AndyO: If you just need a UTF-8 decoder that's small, simple, and bug-free (surprisingly many are buggy!), I highly recommend this one: https://bjoern.hoehrmann.de/utf-8/decoder/dfa/ It's near-optimal in terms of size and has good performance. [Mine in musl libc](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/multibyte) (internal.c and ,h files) is a slightly smaller and faster but more difficult to understand and not documented for easy reuse outside the way it's used for implementing the standard functions.

Comment: Windows 10 supports UTF8 for console programs only. The WinAPI functions only support UTF16, or ANSI. `MultiByteToWideChar` will convert from UTF8 to UTF16

Comment: @BarmakShemirani What the... what kind of sorcery is this `MultiByteToWideChar` and why isn't this mentioned more often?! I don't have even set a locale or define the literal as u8 - it just works... with 3 lines of code! :)

Comment: *"dubious historical reasons"* - There's nothing dubious about that change breaking [IsDBCSLeadByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-isdbcsleadbyte). And a number of other API calls as well as CRT functions. Microsoft has (had?) a history of providing an unprecedented compatibility story, for developers and users alike. No matter how attractive flipping that switch may be to some, with the amount of unknown repercussions it's just not something you'd do lightly. The risks involved kept pushing this feature towards the bottom of the priority list.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't see any plausible way it breaks that IsDBCSLeadByte, which is perfectly well-defined for UTF-8 (aside from the D in the name being a misnomer). The dubious historical reason was just that *applications* could historically assume "multibyte" just meant "1-2 bytes" rather than "1-4 bytes", and might break from this assumption no longer being true.

Comment: @R..: The documented contract for `IsDBCSLeadByte` (*"A lead byte is the first byte of a two-byte character in a double-byte character set (DBCS) for the code page."*) is invalidated by allowing UTF-8. That's a breaking change, that cannot be fixed by updating the implementation. Applications did not assume. They were written against a published contract.

Comment: @IInspectable: If you really want to continue the definition of that function as "first byte of a two-byte character" you can define it as true for bytes C2..DF and false for everything else. I'm not sure if anyone wants to do that; it's probably preferable to redefine it as "first byte of a >1-byte character". I'm not sure what they did. But as noted in the linked article, what MS found is that there argument that it would break things was rather bogus, and nothing of consequence broke when they finally changed it.

Comment: @R..: That's a wikipedia article. That's not an official statement from Microsoft. You are probably mixing up two statements here anyway (*"Microsoft claims this option might break some functions [...]. In reality, functions do not break as much as users may expect"*). The second statement has no attribution, and is probably just an opinionated statement from the author. If you know of any official resources backing those claims, bring them forth.

Comment: As for making `IsDBCSLeadByte` UTF-8 aware, without breaking the contract: That simply won't work. Your proposed solution breaks software that counts codepoints, for example, by moving through a byte stream a character at a time, skipping the following character in case of a lead byte.

Comment: @IInspectable: For many years, Microsoft claimed it would break things badly and that was their justification for refusing to do it. So if they've changed their minds on the refusal, it's likely that they've either done work to determine that nothing significant broke, or they knew their argument was weak all along and didn't need any new work to determine that.

Comment: @IInspectable: As for `IsDBCSLeadByte`, the contract of that function is insufficient for counting characters, and it simply shouldn't be used. That doesn't mean supporting UTF-8 is "breaking its contract". Rather it's just exposing that the contract is not useful for what applications wanted to do with it.

Comment: Either provide references, or clearly mark your comments as speculation. I don't see Microsoft having changed their mind. They added a beta feature to an insider build, presumably to quantify the amount of breakage. That feature may just as well be gone next week. As for the contract of `IsDBCSLeadByte`: It is sufficient to implement the algorithm I sketched out above. You are reading something into it that's just not there, to support your opinion. If you want to make a strong point, explain, why the published contract is allegedly insufficient to support the algorithm mentioned above.